# How to retrieve values from a div in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I have the following Html.

```html
<div id="project-options" data-suggestions="[SW Work Flow Test (SW_TEST)]</div>
```

I want to get the value of data-suggestions and parse it get the following final  result.

Expected Result.

Data-suggestions value = "SW Work Flow Test (SW_TEST)"

**Final value after parsing = SW_TEST**

Many thanks.

Comment: I've done
$("#project-options").find("data-suggestions")[1]
    
$("#project-options").children('items[0]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("project-options");
  var json_data = JSON.parse(element.dataset.suggestions);
  
  json_data.forEach(function(obj) { 
    var items = obj['items'];
    $.each(items, function(index, item){
      var txt = item['label'];
      var regex = /\((.*)\)/i;
      console.log(txt.match(regex)[1]);
    });
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project-options" data-suggestions="[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Recent Projects&quot;,&quot;items&quot;:[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;SW Work Flow Test (SW_TEST)&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;10109&quot;,&quot;icon&quot;:&quot;http://10.17.252.6:8080/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&amp;pid=10109&amp;avatarId=10011&quot;,&quot;selected&quot;:true}]}]"> Admin</div>
```

hope that helps!